# Blazor WASM - instead of rendering my desired component, it redirects me to the login page component

Tags: c#, .net-core, frontend, blazor, single-page-application

I have a razor component. When I enter the route information of this component in the url section in the browser, it redirects me to the login page component. My goal is to use this component without authentication, so I think I have a problem. I will share the codes of my component and App.razor page below . Also This project is realized using .net core 6.0, the interactivity mode is set to whatever the default value is. If you need more information please let me know in the comments . Thanks in advance .

Its the component.

````
@page "/postmobil/{tenant}/{id:guid}"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@inject IStringLocalizer<PostMobil> L
@inject HttpClient _httpClient
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions```

@if (isLoaded is true)
{

    <MudContainer class="flex-container">
        <MudPaper class="header">
            <h1>@postDetailsDto.Baslik</h1>
        </MudPaper>
        <MudPaper class="content bold">
            <p class="bold">@postDetailsDto.OzetMetin</p>
        </MudPaper>
        <MudPaper class="content">
            <p>@postDetailsDto.TamMetin</p>
        </MudPaper>
        @foreach (var icerik in postDetailsDto.Icerikler)
        {
            @if (icerik.Url.EndsWith("jpeg") || icerik.Url.EndsWith("png") || icerik.Url.EndsWith("jpg"))
            {
                <MudPaper class="image-container">
                    <img src=@icerik.Url alt="Image" class="image" />
                </MudPaper>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudPaper class="pdf-container">
                    <a class="pdf-link" href="@icerik.Url" target="_blank">
                        <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.PictureAsPdf" Size="Size.Medium" Class="icon" />
                        <span class="text">@postDetailsDto.Baslik</span>
                    </a>
                </MudPaper>
            }

        }

    </MudContainer>

   [Parameter]
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 [Parameter]
 public String Tenant { get; set; }
 private PostDetailsDto postDetailsDto = new PostDetailsDto();
 private bool isLoaded = false;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await LoadPostWithDetailsAsync();
}

private async Task LoadPostWithDetailsAsync()
{
   
    
        postDetailsDto = await GetPostsWithDetailsAsync(this.Id, 
        this.Tenant, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        postDetailsDto.OzetMetin = StripHTML(postDetailsDto.OzetMetin);
        postDetailsDto.TamMetin = StripHTML(postDetailsDto.TamMetin);
        isLoaded = true;

        StateHasChanged();
    
 }




}

else
{
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    
}
````

Now its the App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
                     
                 <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(BaseLayout)">
                        <NotAuthorized>
                            @if (@context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated is true)
                            {
                                <p>You are not authorized to be here.</p>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                  
                               <Login/>

                            }
                        </NotAuthorized>
                  </AuthorizeRouteView>
       </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(NotFound)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  What version of Net?  What settings for Interactivity.  Also, it might help your cause if you explained - "but I cannot achieve the result I want in the rendering of the component with the incoming data."   What is actually being displayed when not logged in?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I revised my question in line with the direction you gave and tried to complete the missing parts.